# Jquery Multiple Toggles - Continued Animation Error

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, bbcode

I am attempting to get spoilers working on a forum using BBCode. This is the code that I am using at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('.toggle_container').hide();

$('h5.trigger').click(function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
return false;
});

});
</script>

<div class="spoiler">
<h5 class="trigger"><a href="#">Show</a></h5>
<div class="toggle_container">
<div class="block">
    {param}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically, this works fine if there is only one spoiler shown on a page. However, if say two are on a page, the animation would show and then hide. If there are three on a page, the animation would run three times (show, hide, show). How can I make it so that regardless of how many spoilers are on a page the spoiler only opens or closes once.

Comment: Works for me as written.

Comment: Same here: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/6emtM/

Comment: Hmm. View this page: http://www.habboxforum.com/showthread.php?t=754614&page=2

And click one of the spoilers Show and you'll see it bounces three times because there are three on the page.

Comment: Should work as it is but only if the script appears on the page just once. I'm guessing it's part of a template and included once per spoiler. If so, then move the script out of the template and onto the page proper.

Comment: Right okay. I shall see if I can find a place to add it so it works across the forum.